# Do not produce output when process does not exist

Tags: ps

I would be happy if the following command produced no output if `tail` was not running:

```
ps --no-headers $(pidof tail)
```

Instead I get:

```
  964 pts/2    00:00:01 bash
 4393 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: Does your version of `ps` recognise the `-C cmdlist` option?

Comment: It does, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your version of `ps` supports the `-C` option:

```
ps --no-headers -C tail
```

If not, you can run `ps` only if `pidof` succeeds:

```
pid=$(pidof tail) && ps --no-headers ${pid}
```

or (for Zsh):

```
pid=$(pidof tail) && ps --no-headers $=pid
```

(thanks to [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles)!).

Comment: In zsh, use `ps --no-headers $=pid`

Answer (score 0):

`pidof` and `pgrep` are nice commands to determine what's running in a system, but unfortunately both are unavailable on some operating systems. This should work on most flavours of Unix, BSD and Linux:

```
ps aux | grep tail | grep -v grep
```

which removes the grep command itself.

Answer (score 0):

With `pgrep`, you can list the PID and the commands, with empty input of no process matches:

```
pgrep -a tail
```

If you want more control over what fields are displayed, call `pidof` or `pgrep`, then call `ps` only if the list of processes is non-empty. You can use a temporary variable:

```
pids=$(pgrep -d, tail)
[ -z "$pids" ] || ps --no-headers -p "$pids"
```

or `ifne` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
pgrep tail | ifne xargs ps --no-headers
```